# Drupal, Views, Exposed filter: custom default selected tags

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I'm using Drupal, Views with a exposed filter (using taxonomy).
My customer wants  to set from back-end the default selected tags (in order to pre-filter the views content).

In the exposed filter settings, there is functionality. However, it doesn't work properly: when I click on "Select None" link (I'm using better_exposed_filter module) I expect none of the tags are selected, instead, the default configuration (default selected tags) are selected, so actually it doesn't work anymore. I hope it is clear.

So, I was wondering if I can prepare a custom menu in which my user can check/uncheck the default selected tags in the view.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a new homepage with a CCK forward link.

My customer can select the tags in the View, and copy paste the URL after the changes.

The homepage automatically forward to the personalized view URL.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with hook_forms_alter to change the default selected entries, but if the exposed filter isn't using your selected ones by default then there may be a bug that's worth filing on the module.

Comment: no actually he is using my selected ones, but I lose the "unselect all" functionality (so here there is probably the bug: when I click on unselect all, my default selection is restored instead)